# Open API 3 - How to describe a query parameter that is an array of integers but can be a single item?

Tags: swagger, jsonschema, openapi, ajv

Using Open API 3.0.1, I'm trying to describe a *query* parameter of type "integer", lets say we call it `ids`, that can be alone or can be an array.

For example:

`/my-endpoint?ids=111`

or

`/my-endpoint?ids=111&ids=222`

I did try:

```
- name: ids
  in: query
  required: false
  schema:
    type: array
    items:
      type: integer
```

And I understand that `style: form` and `explode: true` [are the default](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.1.md#fixed-fields-10).

But when I validate this with actual requests (I use [express-openapi-validate](https://github.com/Hilzu/express-openapi-validate#readme) which is a wrapper around [Ajv](https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv)), I get those errors:

*/my-endpoint?ids=111*

```
"Error while validating request: request.query.ids should be array"
```

*/my-endpoint?ids=111&ids=222&ids=333*

```
"Error while validating request: request.query.ids[0] should be integer"
```

And If I use "string" instead of "integer":

```
- name: ids
  in: query
  required: false
  schema:
    type: array
    items:
      type: string
```

*/my-endpoint?ids=111*

```
"Error while validating request: request.query.ids should be array"
```

*/my-endpoint?ids=111&ids=222&ids=333*

```
Valid!
```

How should I describe this `ids` parameter, which must be integer values?

**UPDATE**: I now understand that any query parameters will be a `string` when deserialized by an Express server (which I use). But I'm still unable to have a *single element* array to work!

Comment: Your original example (with just an array of integers) is actually the correct definition for your use case. The validation error is probably a bug in the validation library or server-side framework that you use.

Comment: Good to know, thank you @Helen

Comment: To receive it as an array server side, name your parameter `"ids[]"` istead of `"ids"`

Answer (score 4):

After the comment from @Helen, I did try another validation library, [express-openapi-validator](https://github.com/cdimascio/express-openapi-validator) and now it works well with:

```
- name: ids
  in: query
  required: false
  style: form
  explode: true
  schema:
    type: array
    items:
      type: integer
```

With [express-openapi-validate](https://github.com/Hilzu/express-openapi-validate), the only way I've been able to make it work is using:

```
- name: ids
  in: query
  required: false
  schema:
    anyOf:
      - type: array
        items:
          type: string
          pattern: '^\d+$'
      - type: string  
        pattern: '^\d+$'
```

So I suggest you use [express-openapi-validator](https://github.com/cdimascio/express-openapi-validator) with an Express server.